# How can i switch this array to a user unput

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

The array goes into a selection sort which sorts it into descending order. I need to make the input flexible so that it could have any amount the user intends. I don't know how to do this as I have tried and it gives me a weird letter combination when I print out the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Size;
    Size = sc.nextInt();
    int userInput[] = new int[Size];
    System.out.print("Initial Array : ");
    printExpenses(userInput);
    expensedescending(userInput);
}
```

Comment: What is it giving you a weird letter combination ? The code above ?

Comment: I edited the code and told that when I print the array it gives me a weird combination

Comment: use  "Arrays.toString(userInput);" eg "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userInput));"  if you want to see the contents of the array instead of the "weird" object reference to it. - but can you give your actual question because I am not sure where you are actually stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array but not putting values into it, you should add this after your array declaration :

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++)
  userInput[i] = sc.nextInt();
```

Also, you should follow [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your variable `Size` to `size` (variable names should be camelCase)

The garbage characters you see is because no data initialization is done when doing `new int[]`. The data referenced by the array is then the data that was in the computer memory in this place before allocation.